# Windows user account gets automatically locked

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, user-accounts

One of the user accounts on a Windows 2003 server is frequently locked. Each time the "Account is locked" (roughly translated) checkbox is enabled in the Account Properties -> Account tab. The event viewer only mentions that the account is locked, or that I've unlocked it.

However, I don't see any message why the account gets locked in the first place.
Are there know reasons why an account gets locked, or is there a way to find out why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We finally managed to find the cause:

- The local user account has the same name as the server account, but has a different password.

Windows mixes the accounts/passwords somewhere.
Changing one of the usernames fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like someone or a process is trying to login to the account and keeps locking it. You need to enable  auditing of failed login attempts.

If your machine is on a domain you can do the following:
[Audit Active Directory Objects in Windows Server 2003](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814595)

If your machine is not on a domain, try the following: 
[Logging Failed Log-in Attempts](http://www.visualwin.com/Log-in/logging-failed-logins.html)

This should give you an idea of the machine/process that is trying to login as that user.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of common causes.

- Users who use suspend on laptops and take them on/off the domain.
- People who leave RDP sessions logged on and change their password subsequent to logging on.
- Users who logon to more than one machine at a time and change their password.
- Old credentials stored in user accounts > advanced.
- Scheduled tasks or services with old/incorrect credentials.